# Rotate canvas along its center based on user touch - Android

Tags: android, rotation, touch, android-canvas

I want to rotate the canvas circularly on its center axis based on user touch.

Like a old phone dialer .

i want to rotate based on center

but

Now  its rotating based on top left corner .so i am able to see only 1/4 for rotation of image.

I have tried like as follows

```
onDraw(Canvas canvas){
  canvas.save();
  // do my rotation
  canvas.rotate(rotation,0,0);
  canvas.drawBitmap( ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap(),0,0,p );
  canvas.restore();
}

@Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                  float x = e.getX();
              float y = e.getY();
              updateRotation(x,y);
              mPreviousX = x;
              mPreviousY = y;
            invalidate();
        }

  private void updateRotation(float x, float y) {

          double r = Math.atan2(x - centerX, centerY - y);
            rotation = (int) Math.toDegrees(r);
        }
```

Comment: what the current output?

Comment: i want to rotate based on center but its rotating based on top left corner .so i am able to see only 1/4 for rotation of image.

Comment: Your question is answered here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166917/android-how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-on-a-center-point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this to your custom view methods

```
@Override     
public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){ 
  super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);         

  screenW = w;         
  screenH = h; 
}
```

This method will give you the canvas size then use

> canvas.rotate(rotation, screenW / 2, screenH / 2);

Comment: +1 for answer. Thanks dude this onSizeChanged method i left previously. now its working great.

Comment: great, if you need to rotate an image which is not in the center of the canvas, then just enter image's center as pivot rotate coordinates

Answer (score 2):

Pass the point of rotation to rotate api:

```
canvas.rotate(rotation, 0, centerY);
```

Comment: thanks  +1 for answer but canvas.rotate(rotation,0,centerY) gives me only half side (right half rotation) ,But canvas.rotate(rotation,centerX,centerY) gives me exact circular rotation on its midpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rotating the Canvas you can use 
    x=0;

```
x=x+50;
yourview.setRotation(x);
```

use this on touch event and 
   x=x-50 for rotating backword

I think it will help