# Floating Button rotation depending on View Pager scroll state

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, floating-action-button

I'm developing an Android app and there is a feature I want to implement but because of lacking experience I don't know how to do it and unfortunately googling it didn't help.

So, there is a *ViewPager* with two tabs and a *FloatingActionButton* with an arrow image and what I want to do is to rotate the arrow depending on the scrolling state of pager (on first tab it should be a left arrow, then between the tabs it should smoothly rotate to face up or down (doesn't really matter), and finally on the second tab it should become a right arrow, and vice versa).

I've been trying *RotateAnimation* class, but I didn't manage to make it work.

Please notice that my app's *minSdkVersion* is 14 (Jelly Bean +), so Vector drawables and other just-Lollipop or even KitKat things wouldn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can look into making a canvas and calling rotate function on ViewPager's setOnPageChangeListener ( assuming you are using ViewPager for the 2 fragments)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413710/android-how-can-i-rotate-an-arrow-image-around-a-fixed-point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you're using includes the shadow in it's view, which means it's rotated along with the rest of the view when using `setRotation`. You can get around this by wrapping your Floating Action Button in a FrameLayout, remove the `fab_icon` attribute from your FAB, and add an ImageView on top of your FAB like so:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fab_colorNormal="?attr/colorAccent"
        app:fab_colorPressed="?attr/colorAccentHighlight"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fab_icon_overlay"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_icon_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_content_add"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Then, instead of rotating the FAB, you rotate the ImageView. The result is that the FAB appears to rotate, because it's a circle and the icon inside it is rotating. Please note that the value of `android:layout_marginTop` must be the negative value of `fab_shadow_offset` for the icon to be perfectly centered. The default value is 3dp.

What you want to do now is combine Ashtons answer with a call to `setRotation(float rotation)`, please note that the rotation is in degrees (`0.0f` - `360.0f`).

A solution might look like this:

```
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    // positionOffset ranges from 0.0f to 1.0f, multiply it by 180.0f to rotate the 
    // icon clockwise, making the icon appear flipped when scrolled to the last page.
    // Multiply by -180.0f to rotate counter-clockwise.
    fabIconOverlay.setRotation(positionOffset * 180.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `PageChangedListener` on a view pager. Then listening to `onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)` will tell you what you need to calculate the rotation angle.

Note that this is not an animation--you are going to explicitly set the rotation of the button based on the scroll of the viewpager. You need to keep track of the current page and compare that to the page you're getting in the position argument of `onPageScrolled`. To do this, you can use my code as an example:

```
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    if (currentPagePosition != position && (int) positionOffset == 0 && positionOffsetPixels == 0) {
        // New page is set!
        currentPagePosition = position;
        onNewPage(currentPagePosition);
    } else {
        if (positionOffset == 0 && positionOffsetPixels == 0) {
            // User scrolled a little, then let go 
            // and it went back without changing position
            onNewPage(position);
            return;
        }
        if (position == currentPagePosition) {
            onPageScrolledToLeft(position, positionOffset);
        } else if (position < currentPagePosition) {
            onPageScrolledToRight(position, positionOffset);
        }
    }
}
```

With this, now you can implement those two methods to use positionOffset to calculate the rotation angle. Note that `onPageScrolledToLeft` means that the current page is moving left, or the user is scrolling to the right. When this happens, values of `positionOffset` will go from values of 1.0 to 0.0. When `onPageScrolledToRight` triggers, `positionOffset` will go from 0.0 - 1.0. Now after calculating the proper rotation (ie, 0.5 should probably be 0 degrees) you can use a view's `setRotation(float rot)` method.

Comment: I've tried _setRotation_ as well, what's weird it rotated the whole button but its drawable. I think that's the problem of _FloatingActionButton_ implementation, isn't it?

Comment: How did you implement the floating action button? Did you use a 3rd party library?

Comment: @Nicklas yeah, it's [this](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button) one. I think it's the best one out there.

Comment: Looking through the source, It is probably because of how the button is composed. One way to get around this would be to simply subclass the `FloatingActionButton`, add methods like `rotateTo(float angle)`` then override `onDraw()` such that you rotate the canvas before calling super to draw the button as it normally would.

Comment: In my experiments I didn't find any issues with using `setRotation`, except that the shadow of the FAB is rotated as well, which looks a little weird, and it's not the intended behaviour of a shadow.