# Android Rotate Picture before saving

Tags: android, image, file, io, camera

I just finished my camera activity and it's wonderfully saving the data.
What I do after the picture is taken:

```
protected void savePictureData() {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(this.photo);
        fs.write(this.lastCamData);
        fs.close(); //okay, wonderful! file is just written to the sdcard

        //---------------------
        //---------------------
        //TODO in here: dont save just the file but ROTATE the image and then save it!
        //---------------------
        //---------------------


        Intent data = new Intent(); //just a simple intent returning some data...
        data.putExtra("picture_name", this.fname);
        data.putExtra("byte_data", this.lastCamData);
        this.setResult(SAVED_TOOK_PICTURE, data);
        this.finish(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        this.IOError();
    }

}
```

What I want to is already as comment given in the code above. I dont want the image just to be saved to file but to be rotated and then saved! Thanks!

//**EDIT**: What I am currently up to (Works but still runs into memory issues with large images)

```
byte[] pictureBytes;
Bitmap thePicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(this.lastCamData, 0, this.lastCamData.length);
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.postRotate(90);
thePicture = Bitmap.createBitmap(thePicture, 0, 0, thePicture.getWidth(), thePicture.getHeight(), m, true);

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
thePicture.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
pictureBytes = bos.toByteArray();

FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(this.photo);
fs.write(pictureBytes);
fs.close();
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("picture_name", this.fname);
data.putExtra("byte_data", pictureBytes);
this.setResult(SAVED_TOOK_PICTURE, data);
this.finish();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to rotate a bitmap on a center point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166917/android-how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-on-a-center-point)

Comment: nah, not really, its more about how to rotate and save afterwards

Comment: alright my solution seems to work - cleaned the project...

Comment: so which one is working, edited in question or accepted answer  proposal?

Comment: the edit is working when theres enough free memory (what should be the normal case) ;)

Comment: Nice solution.work well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you create your `FileOutputStream` you can create a new `Bitmap` from the original that has been transformed using a `Matrix`.  To do that you would use this method:

```
createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter)
```

Where the `m` defines a matrix that will transpose your original bitmap.

For an example on how to do this look at this question:
[Android: How to rotate a bitmap on a center point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166917/android-how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-on-a-center-point)

Comment: hey, take a look on my edit. i tried to but it doesnt work like this... :/

Comment: I'm trying something like that. But everytime I copy the bitmap I got an exception: out of memory...

Comment: @JoubertVasconcelos, you need to scale down the image then.

Answer (score 26):

Read the path from sd card and paste the following code...It'll Replace the existing photo after rotating it..

Note: Exif doesn't work on most of the devices, it returns incorrect data so it's good to hard code the rotation before saving to any degree you want to, Just change the angle value in postRotate.

```
    String photopath = tempphoto.getPath().toString();
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photopath);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    FileOutputStream fOut;
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(tempphoto);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem that we have the programmers with the photos comes from the bitmap class! Always, you pass image for bitmap class this one rotates photo to 90 degrees. Then the solution is that always that we use a bitmap class and we need to show de photo we need to apply 'matrix.postRotate(90);' to create a rotated bitmap.

Answer (score 2):

```
bitmap = RotateBitmap(bitmap, 90);

public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle)
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```