# Android change photo orientation for upload

Tags: android, orientation, photo

I have found lots of solution to change photo orientation for DISPLAY, and succeeded. But now I need to upload that photo by using file.path. Is there anyway to directly change the photo orientation but not just display differently?

```
CustomMultiPartEntity multipartContent = new CustomMultiPartEntity(
new CustomMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {
       @Override
       public void transferred(long num) {
       Constant.Process = (int) ((num / (float) totalSize11) * 100);}
});

multipartContent.addPart("key", new StringBody(Constant.Key));
multipartContent.addPart("userfile", new FileBody(new File(up.FilePath)));
httpPost.setEntity(multipartContent);
HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
response = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());
```

Something like that, I need to insert a FileBody by a FilePath into that 'multipartContent', then upload, is there anyway to upload a correct orientation photo??

Thank you very much!

EDIT: This is my onclick method to have camera, how can I add code to rotate image before it was saved?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v == btn_camera) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

        String newPicFile = "Miuzz"+ df.format(date) + ".jpg";
        String outPath = "/sdcard/" + newPicFile;
        File outFile = new File(outPath);

        mUri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);

        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);

        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is a photo? here's a method to rotate a bitmap if that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015372/how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-90-degrees

Comment: i know how to rotate image,but i wanna know how to directly change images' property from landscape to portrait...:( i need to upload it..

Comment: Did you figure it out how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no way of modifying the orientation of the photo file other other than to load the image, rotate it manually and re-save it in it's correct orientation.

See this question for some details on how to save the image once it's rotated: [Android Rotate Picture before saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606046/android-rotate-picture-before-saving)

Edit: Ok, so what you'll want to do is in your onActivityResult() method, load the image and rotate it as you already do. After rotating it, you should have a correctly orientated Bitmap object, then all you need to do is either overwrite your existing photo, or create a new file like this:

```
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
       out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also worth noting, is that if you decide to create a new file, be sure to delete it after your upload is complete otherwise you'll be unnecessarily filling up the user's internal storage.

Comment: thanks for your idea, i have read the post but i have no idea on how to do it, i have edited my question with my onclick method, can u teach me how to do it ,please?:(

Comment: may i know how to overwrite the existing photo? get a bitmap from the filepath, then rotate it, then save it with the same path and same name, done?