# How to open camera landscape mode and capture

Tags: android, android-camera, landscape

I am trying to open phone camera in landscape mode using camera intent and set screen orientation is portrait in manifest file.but i want to open the camera in  landscape mode

Comment: this link might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606046/android-rotate-picture-before-saving

Comment: did you want to create your own camera or you want to use phone's camera in landscape mode

Comment: Google for it first you will find hundreds of example for that

Comment: @VivekMishra i used following code, but not working `  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,
                        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

Comment: Post your Complete camera code in your question

Comment: my code is:   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,
                        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

startActivityForResult(intent,
                        CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: @shakthivel Hi! Please edit your question with all the relevant details from your comments, then delete the "obsolete" ones.