# Java Android - JPEG Image rotation

Tags: java, android, matrix, android-camera2

I'm working on an application to capture images but I'd like to rotate a JPEG image before saving it, I already saw this link : 
 [Android Rotate Picture before saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606046/android-rotate-picture-before-saving)

This is what I'm doing right now.

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
byteBuffer.get(bytes);

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

try {
    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mImageFileName);
    fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried this to rotate the image like this :

```
// Bytes array to bitmap and matrix rotation
Bitmap sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setRotate((float)90, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight());
Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), m, true);

// Bitmap to bytes array
int size = targetBitmap.getRowBytes() * targetBitmap.getHeight();
ByteBuffer targetByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
targetBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(targetByteBuffer);
bytes = targetByteBuffer.array();
```

But when I look into the file into my gallery, I cannot read it, the image seems broken.

EDIT: Doesn't work on Android 7.1.1 :/ Any idea ? Can I do something similar for a video record?

Comment: Is that showing your image into Gallary when you save without rotation.?

Comment: The link you shared - Look at the answer with 17 upvotes

Comment: Yes it does @NikunjParadva

Answer (score 2):

You are Coverting Your `Bitmap` to `bytes array`,
Now You stop That way save `Bitmap` directly to `File`

```
Bitmap sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setRotate((float)90, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight());
Bitmap rotatedBitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), m, true);

// Save Bitmap directly to the file

String filename = "hello.jpg";
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dest = new File(sd, filename);

try {
     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
     out.flush();
     out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: If you get your answer then click on checkmark on the answer

Answer (score 0):

This little change apparently did the trick ! Thanks Nikunj !

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
byteBuffer.get(bytes);

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate((float)90, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
try {
    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mImageFileName);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
    fileOutputStream.flush();
    fileOutputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I know this is old, but sorry i have to confirm. In your example, are you not missing to apply the Matrix that you created ?

You didn't use the matrix you created to apply it to the Bitmap, so ther image will never be rotated ? Shouldn't it look like this...
```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.SetRotate((float)90, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
```