# createBitmap() leads me into a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, bitmap, system, out-of-memory

i try to rotate 3 imageViews (or better the Bitmaps behind them) every 10-100ms. 
i do the rotation like this:

```
ImageView ivLoad;
Bitmap bMapLoad;

....

Matrix mat=new Matrix();
mat.reset();
mat.postScale(1.55f, 1.55f);
mat.postRotate((float)currentLoadDegree+(float)LoadDegree);
bMapLoad = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMapLoadgr, 0, 0, bMapLoadgr.getWidth(), bMapLoadgr.getHeight(), mat, true);
ivLoad.setImageBitmap(bMapLoad);
ivLoad.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);

....
```

the first time i start the app everthing works fine.
second time also works
but the 3rd time i start the app it crashs with the following error:

```
03-27 10:01:09.234: E/AndroidRuntime(3603): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-27 10:01:09.234: E/AndroidRuntime(3603):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)    
03-27 10:01:09.234: E/AndroidRuntime(3603):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)  
03-27 10:01:09.234: E/AndroidRuntime(3603):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
```

after trying around a long time i found out that when i call System.exit(0) in the onDestroy methode everthing works. 
now i don't know if there would be a better way because on google a lot of peaople mean that System.exit(0) is unsafe.

so will i get problems with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't recreate the bitmap on every step of the rotation, instead you should just try to draw it rotated. That's also possible with a Matrix (what you already use) and will avoid the excessive memory usage.

[Android: How to rotate a bitmap on a center point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166917/android-how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-on-a-center-point)

Comment: the problem is that the degrees i rotate depend on data i get over bluetooth. so the degrees change every time. and to rotate the bitmap i have to create a new one.

Comment: and what is the problem with that ? :-? Just save the angle as a member of your class, draw the image rotated each time based on that member, and just update that member whenever you want.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rotating the Bitmap, you could rotate the canvas you are drawing on.

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(-canvasWidth/2, -canvasHeight/2);
canvas.rotate(degrees)

canvas.drawBitmap( ... )

canvas.translate(-canvasWidth/2, -canvasHeight/2);
canvas.restore();
```

Now you only get a new bitmap, when the image itself is updated, even though you can rotate it as frequent as you like. But if you get a new Bitmap, you still need to call `Bitmap.recycle()` on the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You get `OutOfMemoryError` because you load the `Bitmap` every time you rotate `ImageView`. You should consider reusing already loaded bitmap. Also call `Bitmap.recycle()` method when you do not need the bitmap any more.

Comment: well the rotation degrees are different every time. i tryed to recycle the bitmap before creating a new one but that crashes the  app because it tryes to draw a recycle bitmap

Comment: Look at @twall's answer - it does make sense. By the way, using `Animation` is an option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application helped =)

Comment: how that link helped you?! I would say that can be temporal work-around but you still have memory leaking in your app..

Comment: well the memory is just leaking bekause the process is running in background. wenn i kill the process all the memory is released. whenn looking on logcat i can see the heap growing without it every time i restart the app. but with the process kill the heap is the same size every time.