# Out of memory error when calling createBitmap

Tags: java, android, image, memory, bitmap

I was trying to fix the issue of [Android Camera Intent Saving Image Landscape When Taken Portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933085/android-camera-intent-saving-image-landscape-when-taken-portrait), but ran into the issue of an `dalvikvm-heap Out of memory on a 63489040-byte allocation.` error. I looked at [createBitmap() leads me into a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885647/createbitmap-leads-me-into-a-java-lang-outofmemoryerror), but that question was not of any help. I'm not sure how to fix this. I tried calling `recycle()`on the bitmap, but that didn't work.

```
String file = getRealPathFromURI(Uri.parse(mUriString));
BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bounds);

BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, opts);
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(file);
String orientString = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
int orientation = orientString != null ? Integer.parseInt(orientString) : ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
int rotationAngle = 0;

switch(orientation) {
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
    rotationAngle = 90;
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
    rotationAngle = 180;
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
    rotationAngle = 270;
}

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(rotationAngle, (float) bm.getWidth() / 2, (float) bm.getHeight() / 2);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bounds.outWidth, bounds.outHeight, matrix, true);
bm.recycle();
```

This code reads the EXIF data and orientates the image properly.

I should also add that I am compressing the image here:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
rotatedBitmap.recycle();
baos.close();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can reduce the memory when you decode the image in your `BitmapFactory.Options` through skipping `ARGB_8888` and using `RGB_565` instead. and `inDither` to true to preserve image quality.

**sample:**

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
opts.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
opts.inDither = true;
```

Comment: Is there any way this could mess up image compression?

Comment: @lschessinger how could you say that it could mess up compression?

Comment: Nevermind. Unrelated issue (I think).

Answer (score 3):

you could use `opts.inSampleSize = 2 or above` to avoid the `OOM` exception.