# How to reset ImageView angle rotation to default?

Tags: android

I have an ImagaView,in which I set the bitmap and made some rotation using onTouchListener concept.

```
If I set another Bitmap to same imageview,it is displaying in same angle which is left after doing rotation of previous image.
```

So,I just want the ImageView to come in default position.

Thanks

Comment: default is 0.. I don't get the question. Also you don't give far enough info.

Comment: please try to understand,I have an ImageView which is modified by using zoom,pinchzoom,rotate options.And when I come for second time the ImageView is in modified state.I want to set this to default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using different bitmaps then just pass `bmp = null;` or

```
if (null!=bmp){
    bmp.recycl();
    bmp=null;
}
```

and in your imageView display the current bitmap that has been modified.

```
if (null!=change)
    imageview.setImageBitmap(change);
else 
    imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

and so on " in case you having multiple bitmaps. you can check my application on android market which i'm doing the same thing you asked ! StyleMe - Photo Editor.

### EDIT

in this case you have to

```
@Override 
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if ( all your bitmaps != null ){
        all.recycle;
        all=null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You already have code to rotate imageView when pinching use that to reset the imageview's rotation to 0(zero).

Btw the function to ratate a view is

```
myImageView.setRotation(float rotationInDegrees);
```

e.g.

```
myImageView.setRotation(0);
```

Call this when you apply the new image source to the imageview.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29)

Answer (score 1):

try this link's this may help you

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/

and

[Corresponding rotated object to numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459300/android-corresponding-rotated-object-to-numeric-values?lq=1)