# Rotate an image multiple times but keep the corners aligned

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation

I tried to rotate an image with following code, but I found the generated image gets bigger and bigger:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(10);
Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, 
        image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

You can see the pictures:

**Original**

[image]

**Rotate 10 degree**

[image]

**Rotate 10 degree again**

[image]

**Rotate 10 degree again**

[image]

The blue rectangles are full images.

You can see the images getting bigger and bigger(although the size of sofa is not changed), and the 4 corners of original image are not on the borders of new images later.

How to change the code to keep the corners on the border(just like the 2nd image)?

I forgot to say I've created a demo project on github. You can clone it, the main java code is here:

https://github.com/freewind/Android-RotateTest/blob/master/src/com/example/MyActivity.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your code and after some rotation it crashed with the OutOfMemory exception cause each time a new bitmap is created which is very resource intensive. You should never never! use createBitMap() in iteration. I made some modification to your image rotation code and now it's running as expected.
Here is the code:

```
private void addListeners() {
    this.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

            //copying the image matrix(source) to this matrix 
            matrix.set(imageView.getImageMatrix());

            matrix.postRotate(10, imageView.getWidth()/2, imageView.getHeight()/2);
            imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);

            //checking the size of the image
            Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
            imageInfo(bmp);
        }
    });
}
```

also set the **scale type of the imageView to matrix**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#336699"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:padding="2px"
    android:src="@drawable/m" />
```

And if we want to get the rotated bitmap from ImageView, do this:

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView() {
    // this is the important code :)
    // Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will be null
    imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    imageView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    imageView.layout(0, 0, imageView.getMeasuredWidth(), imageView.getMeasuredHeight());
    imageView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache());
    imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
    return b;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: what's `imageInfo(bmp)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You must rotate the first image. Save the first image into a variable and then create a copy. When you rotate, always make a fresh copy from the original and rotate that one.

**EDIT**

Change your code to this:

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.setRotate(10);
            Bitmap copy = image;
            Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(copy, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            setNewImage(newImage);
        }
```

Comment: Hey, I'm very sorry, but this is the problem. If you rotate it 20 deg from the start, it will be just fine. Let me look through your code to improve my answer.

Comment: Sometimes it's impossible to always use the first image. e.g. Rotate it, then zoom it, then rotate it. I found the solution of "ImageView with matrix" provided by karn works very well.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to see your images, yet I had the same problem, each time I tried to rotate an image it seemed to resize its self.

I managed to write some code that could successfully turn my image.
My first tip to you is that when you attempt to create an animated spinning picture you should not create a new Bitmap every time, since this will drive the GC crazy and reduce performance speed!

Here's the code that works for me, to spin an image without resizing it:

```
public static Matrix rotateMatrix(Bitmap bitmap, Shape shape, int rotation) {

        float scaleWidth = ((float) shape.getWidth()) / bitmap.getWidth();
        float scaleHeight = ((float) shape.getHeight()) / bitmap.getHeight();

        Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
        rotateMatrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        rotateMatrix.postRotate(rotation, shape.getWidth()/2, shape.getHeight()/2);
        rotateMatrix.postTranslate(shape.getX(), shape.getY());


        return rotateMatrix;

    }
```

Note: The shape object just contains the real dimensions of the object you are trying to spin, eg 100x100.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's because he filters the image. If you rotate, you have to make a new bitmap.

Comment: About your code, shall we set the returning matrix to ImageView?