# How to make a custom grid with images in android ?

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I want to make a `custom grid` with images that we usually see for gallery in android phones

[image]

I have been searching it for couple of hours. But no luck favours and finally I am making an attempt to ask question here. Can someone please suggest me how to achieve this kind of gridview. Or do I need to follow any other approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]See the code for the **main.xml** and **griditem.xml** we have to just set rotation on imageview and margin according to the rotation we have set.

**Important Note**

**If your min SDK version is 11 than use property** android:rotation="20" **bcz it is available since API Level 11 so if you want to run it lower version than use the code of rotation describe in adapter class**

Suppose I have fixed and **ImageView** size 100dp*100dp and If I set Rotation by

```
android:rotation="20"
```

than obviouslly our images will cut down from bottom and top in grid view so set it's margin according to the rotation.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit">
</GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**griditem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#000">
<RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="150dp">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image1" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image2" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image3" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#fff"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
 import android.annotation.TargetApi;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.graphics.Matrix;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
 import android.widget.GridView;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;


 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
 public class MainActivity extends Activity{
String[] logtag=new String[]{"Log.e","Log.d","Log.i"};
GridView gv;
GridAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    gv=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    adapter=new GridAdapter(this);
    gv.setAdapter(adapter);


}
class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    LayoutInflater lf;
    Context context;

    public  GridAdapter(MainActivity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        context=activity;
        lf=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return logtag.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView==null){
            viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            convertView=lf.inflate(R.layout.griditem, null);
            viewHolder.image1=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            viewHolder.image2=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            viewHolder.image3=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            viewHolder.text=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11){
        RotateBitmap(viewHolder.image1,R.drawable.image1);
        RotateBitmap(viewHolder.image2,R.drawable.image2);
        RotateBitmap(viewHolder.image3,R.drawable.image3);
        }else{
            viewHolder.image1.setRotation(20);
            viewHolder.image2.setRotation(20);
            viewHolder.image3.setRotation(20);
        }
        viewHolder.text.setText(logtag[position]);
        return convertView;
    }
    class ViewHolder{
        ImageView image1;
        ImageView image2;
        ImageView image3;
        TextView text;
    }
    public void RotateBitmap(ImageView imageView, int imageid){
        Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageid);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(20);
        Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, myImg.getWidth(), myImg.getHeight(),matrix, true);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(rotated);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `FrameLayout` with 3 `ImageView`for grid Item. Then use the following code in your `BaseAdapter` class to rotate the `ImageView`'s.

```
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
imagView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Add necessary margins to separate the `ImageView`

Comment: could you give some more other way !! The images were cropping as per angle @nirmal raghavan

Comment: This code would leak memory, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159852/why-this-image-switching-code-has-memory-leak

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `ImageBlock` class located in the source code of the [`Android ImageGallery` project](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/packages/apps/Camera/src/com/android/camera/ImageGallery2.java). These `ImageBlock`s are managed and placed into `GridViewSpecial`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can can use following code to rotate images from center point

```
Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight, config);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(mRotation,source.getWidth()/2,source.getHeight()/2);
canvas.drawBitmap(source, matrix, new Paint());
```