# Rotating bitmap in main game loop without overloading GC in Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, garbage-collection

What is the correct way to rotate bitmap every frame in main game loop?
What I have tried:

I created rotated bitmap every frame:

```
Bitmap image, tmp;
Matrix m;
...
public void mainGameLoop(Canvas c){
    m.reset();
    m.postRotate(angle);
    tmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, width, height, m, true);
    c.drawBitmap(tmp, 50, 50, null);
}
```

However, because Bitmap.createBitmap creates bitmap every frame Garbage Collector works so madly, it causes low FPS.

I have tried saving bitmap in array at all angles, and just taking bitmap which I want to. However, this needs a lot of RAM and app just couldn't launch at high screen resolutions.

If you have any ideas, please comment below.

Comment: Why you use createBitmap every frame?! Create it ones and use rotate method in canvas

Comment: How to do it? Can you give me example?

Comment: refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166917/android-how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-on-a-center-point .. you can apply the rotaion while drawing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some think like this:

```
Bitmap image;
Matrix m;
.
.
.
public YourClass(){
    m = new Matrix();
    image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, width, height,);
}
.
.
.
public void mainGameLoop(Canvas c){
    m.setRotate(angle, imageCenterX, imageCenterY);
    yourCanvas.drawBitmap(image, m, null);
}
```